# retrieve avatar from user class swift parse

Tags: image, swift, parse-platform

I would like to retrieve the user's avatar from Parse. I create a File column in the User default Parse class and i successfully uploaded an image but i dont know what is wrong with this func:

```
 var query = PFQuery(className: "User")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[AnyObject]?,error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let imagesobjects = objects as! [PFObject]
            for object : PFObject in objects as! [PFObject] {
                let image = object["Avatar"] as! PFFile
                image.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        if let finalimage = UIImage(data: imageData!) {
                            self.avatarImage.image = finalimage
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you. Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do it that hard if you trying to retrieve a current user avatar.

Just do the following :

```
    let avatarFile = PFUser.currentUser()!["avatar"] as PFFile
    avatarFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        if let finalimage = UIImage(data: imageData!) {
            self.avatarImage.image = finalimage
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you are getting with it! Dont forget to mark as answer!

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do it is if you use PFImageView:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var avatarImageView: PFImageView!

 if PFUser.currentUser()!["avatar"] != nil {
      avatarImageView.file = PFUser.currentUser()!["avatar"] as? PFFile
      avatarImageView.loadInBackground()
 }
```